# CSS - How to get rid of these bullet points above all my widgets in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

[image]

So only within my sidebar widgets does this bullet above the widgets occur. I am not sure what custom css code to use to get rid of this. That is why I uploaded the picture of the inspect element to see if anyone can help me identify where the problem is coming from. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `list-style-type:none`?

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the bullets with `list-style` CSS property. Ideally you'll want to use a CSS class to do this and since you're using WordPress try and use a class provided by the widget to hook onto. We hook onto a CSS class so we don't affect all `ul` or `li` on the page.

Not sure what yours would be but it might be something like this pseudo code:

```html
<ul class="widget-alpha">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.widget-alpha {
  list-style: none;
}
```

FWIW, it's a bit odd that I don't see a `ul` for the `li` in the screenshot. The only permitted parents for `li` are `ul`, `ol` and `menu`.

If the `li` is the container element for the widget then the CSS selector would still work as we're not targeting a specific element but a CSS class of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#sidebar-footer-secondary>div>li{
 list-style: none;
}
```

or

```
.sidebar-footer-secondary>div>li{
 list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add class to selector, if you only want to change widget lists.

`li.widget { list-style-type: none; }`